# Alpine 3.8 docker установка xdebug

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose

столкнулся c проблемой, хочу установить xdebug (в контейнер с Alpine 3.8 + php 7.2), использую в имэйдже такую строку `RUN pecl install xdebug-2.6.0 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug` и получаю ошибку, "docker-php-ext-enable not found". Сам модуль ставится. Подскажите, как включить php mod в Alpine (стандартный phpenmod MODULE_NAME не работает) ?

Answer (score 1):

После долгого гугления пришёл к тому, что базовая сборка alpine не поддерживает docker-php-ext-*. По этому решил по-другому, копирую готовый конфиг в контейнер. И ещё, xDebug можно не ставить через pecl, а дёрнуть из репозитория alpine `apk add --no-cache php7-xdebug`